# Trying to get if click on one radion button the other is unclicked

Tags: android

I am trying to find how if you click on one radio button the other is unclicked using java not XML.  I have both of my radioButtons in a tableRow.  When I put them in a radioGroup is messes up the rest of my XML layout.  Basically,if one is clicked make sure the other in not clicked.

```
public void drivable(View v) {
    if (notDrivable.isChecked()) {
        notDrivable.toggle();
    }

}
public void notDrivable(View v) {
    if (drivable.isPressed()) {
        drivable.toggle();
    }
}
```

I figured it out.  I needed to change it from toggle() to notDrivable.setChecked(false);  Here is the code that works.

```
public void drivable(View v) {
    if (notDrivable.isChecked()) {
        notDrivable.setChecked(false);
    }

}
public void notDrivable(View v) {
    if (drivable.isChecked()) {
        drivable.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably should still be using a RadioGroup. There are almost certainly ways you can make it look however you need it to in order to fit with the rest of your layout. Maybe post a picture of how it turns out by default if you use a radio group, and another one of how you want it to look and we can help you to get it looking properly?

Answer (score 0):

as a suggestion you can give it a try.... get the id's for your radio buttons and in their onclick's method make another one unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put an OnClick Listener to each button and with a boolean and if clause determine when a button is clicked if it is selected or not and act accordingly. I hope I helped you.